# Angular 2 BehaviorSubject data manipulation in component reflects in service

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

This is my DataService:

```
private resultsChanged$: BehaviorSubject<Test[]> = 
                         new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);

constructor(private http: Http) { }

public getLatestTrends(): Observable<Test[]> {
    const latestUrl = `api/tests/trends/groupname=${this.group}&name=${this.team}`;
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + latestUrl)
        .switchMap((res) => {
        const json = res.json();
        console.log(json);
        this.resultsChanged$.next(json as Test[]);
        return json;
    });
}

public getSubject(): Observable<Test[]> {
    return this.resultsChanged$.asObservable();
}
```

This is the component that uses the DataService and formats the returned data:

```
private latestTests: Test[];
private subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private testDataService: TestDataService) { }

ngOnInit() {

  this.subscription = this.testDataService.getSubject()
      .subscribe((res) => {
          if (res === undefined || res.length < 1) {
              return;
          }

          this.latestTests = this.getFormattedTests(res.reverse());
      });
}

getFormattedTests(trends) {
    let formattedTests = [];

    if (trends === undefined || trends === null) {
        return formattedTests;
    }
    formattedTests = trends.map((trend) => {

        if (this.isPassed(trend.ran, trend.passed, trend.total)) {
            trend.state = 'check_circle';
            trend.color = 'green';
        } else {
            trend.state = 'warning';
            trend.color = 'red';
        }

        const ranPercent = this.getFixedPercent(trend.ran, trend.total);
        const passPercent = this.getFixedPercent(trend.passed, trend.ran);
        const failPercent = this.getFixedPercent(trend.failed, trend.ran);

        trend.notRun = trend.total - trend.ran;
        trend.ran = `${trend.ran} (${ranPercent})`;
        trend.passed = `${trend.passed} (${passPercent})`;
        trend.failed = `${trend.failed} (${failPercent})`;

        return trend;
    });

return formattedTests;
```

}

The HTML

```
<tr *ngFor="let test of latestTests">
      <td>
        <span><md-icon [ngStyle]="getStateOfBuild(test)">{{test.state}}</md-icon> {{test.versionString}}</span>
      </td>
      <td>{{test.total}}</td>
      <td>{{test.ran}}</td>
      <td>{{test.passed}}</td>
      <td>{{test.failed}}</td>
      <td>{{test.notRun}}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{test.duration | duration }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Okay, so the thing is, when the site loads, the data is formatted and saved in latestTests variable. When i cycle between my routes so the ngInit is called again, the data gets formatted again which i dont understand. The weird thing is that when i console.log(json); in the DataService it logs out the formatted data and not the original... How is that even possible?!
It is as if the BehaviorSubject's data is changed somehow. What am I missing?

Please help and comment if i need to clarify.

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` stores the latest value it received and replays it to every observer on subscription.

Comment: And that is what it is supposed to do, but the latest value seems to change when the component formats it in ngOnInit.. The component shouldn't be able to manipulate the subjects data like that??

Comment: Are you sure you're not manipulating the same instance of the array? Maybe try `this.resultsChanged$.next(Array.from(json));`

Comment: That does not help. I also have tried:
     Object.assign([], json)

Comment: So it works the first time it is loaded, but second time, it tries to format the formatted data. I just dont see where in my code i pass a reference from the formatted data to the behaviorsubject

Comment: Did you forget to unsubscribe maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Take note of the difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject:

**Subject** behaves like an event bus and does not hold data.

**BehaviorSubject** can act like an event bus but will also return the last value in the stream upon subscription.

in your service your can just declare:

```
public mySubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

Now you can use that to do the following:

```
this.testDataService.mySubject.subscribe(
  res => console.log(res),
  error => console.log(error)
);
this.testDataService.mySubject.next('data');
```

That's all. I hope it helps

Comment: The data service should ONLY hold original data, because multiple components use the data, but it seems like it holds the formatted data after my component formats it without calling next on the subject.